# How to get BOINC Manager to work -- broken by recent update

Tags: 14.04, package-management, boinc

I'm currently running Kubuntu 14.04 LTS on my desktop system.  I've also been running various @Home distributed computing clients for years, currently Milkyway and Einstein.  A couple days ago, there was an update -- and the updater wanted to remove BOINC Manager, which provides the interface to control the operation of the @Home clients.

What I've been told by BOINC support is that, for whatever reason, I need to install the version of BOINC Manager from 16.04, in order to use `libwxgtk-webview3.0-0v5` instead of the version without the v5 at the end.  Lacking any apparent way to do that, I tried version locking `libwxgtk-webview3.0-0` and `boinc-manager`, but after the `boinc-client` was updated, BOINC manager won't start -- when invoked from a terminal, it produces *no output at all*, just returning to the prompt after 2-3 seconds.

Given that what BOINC support is telling me isn't possible (installing a Xenial package on Trusty), how can I get `boinc-manager` to work, rather than simply uninstalling if I let it update?

Comment: The only way to get BOINC from Xenial on your system is to compile it manually for 14.04, you can't simply install the software from Xenial onto your Trusty system due to package naming, library versions, etc.  The alternative is to just upgrade to Xenial, but I'm not going to outright suggest that.

Comment: If I could just "upgrade" to Xenial, I might do so.  I don't like what KDE changed for version 5, though, so I'd be changing desktops in any case, which really means clean install.  Which means a whole weekend to get everything set back up, even with "automated" tools to reinstall software.